# File list returns undefined when there are no files

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, while-loop

I'm using this code to return a list of files in a google drive folder. It works really well, up until there is a folder with no files in it. It returns an error that says "Cannot read property 'length' from undefined".

I'm assuming there needs to be a if, else statement in there somewhere, to return "null" or an acceptable exit to the loop besides "undefined", that can be output to the same range listed in the output.

```
function kuehnertdates() {
  var folderId = 'FolderID';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var output = []; 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    output.push([file.getName(), file.getLastUpdated()]);
  }
  output.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1;
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Farms').getRange(2, 17, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function runOne() {
  var folderId = 'folderId';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  if(files.hasNext()) {
    var output = []; 
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      output.push([file.getName(), file.getLastUpdated()]);
    }
    output.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1;
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }else{
    Browser.msgBox('You have no files')
  }
}
```

Comment: That did not work, it still gets hung up at the same spot. would it be easier to first determine whether or not the folder contains any files, then run the output only when files exist?

Comment: It's not hanging up now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*`Files: list` isn't returning undefined when there are no files - when there are no files in the folder, your `output` variable continues to have an empty array value (`[]`) and so the call `output[0]` returns undefined on the call `output[0].length`.*

#### Fix:

You just need to make a small change to only run the code if files actually exist in the folder you're running the `Files: list` method from:

```js
function kuehnertdates() {
  var folderId = '1BYAxJVN5NIMWVsUE2RATl4vPhWBl5Jyc';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  // this is the if condition you need to add
  if (!files.hasNext()){
    return;
  }
  else {
    // continue your code here
    var output = [];
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      output.push([file.getName(), file.getLastUpdated()]);
    }
    output.sort(function(a, b) {
      Logger.log(a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1);
      return a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1;
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Farms').getRange(2, 17, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [MDN web docs - Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)